# Configure MySQL for local and remote access

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm using MySQL server version: 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0 on a Raspberry Pi.

This is my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

#bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

I've tried this:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
Change root password: y
Password
Retyped password
Remove anonymous users: y
Disallow root login remotely: n
Remove test database: y
Reload priviledges: y

CREATE USER 'root'@'%.%.%.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%.%.%.%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEDGES;
service mysql restart
```

In `my.cnf`, with bind-address commented, I can access from `localhost`, but not from remote host using SQL Workbench.

With bind-address uncommented, I cannot access from `localhost`, but I can access from remote host using SQL Workbench, e.g.:

```
mysql -u root
mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address=0.0.0.0'
```

This is my users table:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host, password from mysql.user;
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host      | password                                  |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root | localhost | *054D119DEAD56E226D8356557796BFA72E71BA40 |
| root | %.%.%.%   | *054D119DEAD56E226D8356557796BFA72E71BA40 |
| root | %         | *054D119DEAD56E226D8356557796BFA72E71BA40 |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

How do I configure the server to allow local and remote access for root from any IP?

Comment: Do you have restart MariaDB or read the config new with **FLUSH PRIVILEGES** before you test the access ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen Yes.

Comment: Add a line over **bind-address = 0.0.0.0** with **[mysqld]**. in your case both the server and the local client reads the bind...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a line over **bind-address = 0.0.0.0** with [mysqld] like:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

In your case both, the server and the local client, reads the bind address and the client want to connect to the IP 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 4):

According to [this link](http://dallascao.com/en/solving-the-mysql-unknown-variable-bind-address0-0-0-0-error/) it seems that the mysql client doesn’t recognize the bind address.

In order to connect locally I have to use this line:

```
mysql --no-defaults -u[username] -p[password] [database]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case - I first put the bind-address between the lines and it did not work after

```
systemctl restart mysqld
```

With bind-address at the end it worked:

```
# The MariaDB configuration file 
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.

#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```