# Using Docker and Laravel I got this error with MySQL: “SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory”

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I have an app in laravel 5.2 that connect to my **local** database in mysql, no issues. But, when I put my app inside a docker container, can't connect to my database and I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

If I change DB_HOST in my **.env** file to 127.0.0.1 instead localhost, then I got this other:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I read that problem could be the socket's path in php.ini

```
$ ls -l /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
$ srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 nov 27 08:31 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

So, I included only in case of pdo:

```
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Part of my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=developer
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

My database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

I used docker compose to mount the container, because I plan to create others microservices later:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
   api_test:
      build: .
      ports:
         - "8181:8181"
      env_file:
         - ./.env
      environment:
         - PORT:8181
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.5-apache

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring
WORKDIR /api_test
COPY . /api_test
RUN composer install
RUN a2enmod rewrite
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

I use:

- Debian 9.6, kernel 4.9.0-8-amd64
- Apache/2.4.25
- PHP 7.0.30-0+deb9u1
- MariaDB 10.1.37 database server

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access host database from a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056522/access-host-database-from-a-docker-container)

Comment: If I understand correctly,  Docker is supposed to be contained,  you shouldn't be trying to access sockets, or any file, from your host.

Comment: I tried that just in case. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

localhost or 127.0.0.1 is not correct if you're inside a container because your container will call inside the container and not your host machine.

You have to take your local IP with `ifconfig` command, surely "192.168 ...." and replace localhost by this IP.

You can also create your database in a container, it's easier.

Comment: I already tried that following an advice from another forum. And, create a database in a container is the next step. But I'd like solve this first

Comment: Try to ping this IP from your container, after try to do a telnet command on port 3306, if this is ok, be sure that your env variables are export with a 'env' command inside your container

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Or, one that works for me. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828599/how-to-configure-mysql-for-local-and-remote-access?rq=1) and [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/container-cannot-connect-to-the-hosts-mysql-database/3493/5)

The problem were remote access in my local mysql database. My container's network were different from my local. And, I had no permissions to accept connections from outside.

My my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

The permissions

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'developer'@'%' identified by '123456';
mysql> flush privileges;
```

**EDITED**

I forgot to add that changing my  DB_HOST by my local IP (from my router's asigned ip) into my .env file was neccesary too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command

> docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)

Containers will connect with each other by their ip

For example:
My ip list is:

/nginx - 172.23.0.4

/php - 172.23.0.3

/mysql - 172.23.0.2

Put this ip-address (mysql ip) into your config file instead of 127.0.0.1. Hope that it will help you!

Comment: So the error must be in the network. The funny thing is that if I connect with datagrip to localhost the connection is successful, however if I try to connect with laravel it gives me the error and I have to use this solution.